# DataGridView not update after inserting details on another form [C#]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, sql-server-2014

This is the data grid view form, where the 2nd form will show up when **Add Member** button is clicked.

```
private void btnAddMember_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cashier_NewMember F_Cashier_NewMember = new Cashier_NewMember();

        F_Cashier_NewMember.Show();
    }
```

This is the form where I'll be inserting the member details.

```
private void btnAddMember_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlCon.Open();

            if (btnAddMember.Text == "Add Member")
            {

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLastName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtMobileNo.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtHomeNo.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAddress.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPostcode.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCity.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCountry.Text))
                    MessageBox.Show("All fields are required!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtMemberID.Text))
                    MessageBox.Show("Please generate a Member ID!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                else
                {
                    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("AddOrUpdateMembership", sqlCon);
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", "Add");
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Member_ID", txtMemberID.Text);
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Member_Since_Date", dtpMemberSince.Value.Date);
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", cmbTitle.GetItemText(cmbTitle.SelectedItem));
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", txtFirstName.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", txtLastName.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", dtpDOB.Value.Date);
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cmbGender.GetItemText(cmbGender.SelectedItem));
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile_No", cmbMobileNo.GetItemText(cmbMobileNo.SelectedItem) + txtMobileNo.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Home_No", cmbHomeNo.GetItemText(cmbHomeNo.SelectedItem) + txtHomeNo.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@House_Address", txtAddress.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post_Code", txtPostcode.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City_State", txtState.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", txtCountry.Text.Trim());

                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

This is the code I used to fill up the data gird view

```
public void FillDataGridView()
    {
        Cashier_NewMember F_Cashier_NewMember = new Cashier_NewMember();

        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("ViewOrSearchMembership", sqlCon);
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Member_ID", F_Cashier_NewMember.txtMemberID.Text); 
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
        dgvMembershipDetails.DataSource = dtbl;

        sqlCon.Close();
    }
```

This is the stored procedure code I used to search and fill the data grid view.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ViewOrSearchMembership]
    @Member_ID VARCHAR(10)
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM Member
    WHERE Member_ID LIKE @Member_ID + '%'
```

I've tried adding the **FillDataGridView()** everywhere, but the data grid view is still not updating.

Comment: first :make sure data was inserted in the "member" Table check momber table an tell me if data was inserted

Comment: How/where are you refilling the datatable after you add or update.  Since you are doing it manually, it wont automatocally appear in the DGV  especially since you did not hold onto the table

Comment: @Plutonix erm, I did try on refilling on both of the forms after the Add Button is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this after assigned data source, dgvMembershipDetails.update()

Answer (score 1):

dgvMembershipDetails.Databind() you should be place after assign the datasource line.

Comment: The `DataGridView` has no such method

Answer (score 1):

make sure you dgvMembershipDetails modifiers was public then try to clear datagridview before fill it

```
public void FillDataGridView(){
    Cashier_NewMember F_Cashier_NewMember = new Cashier_NewMember();

    if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        sqlCon.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("ViewOrSearchMembership", sqlCon);
    sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Member_ID", F_Cashier_NewMember.txtMemberID.Text); 
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
    dgvMembershipDetails.DataSource =null;
    dgvMembershipDetails.DataSource = dtbl;

    sqlCon.Close();
}
```